Sumo Networks with Many Disconnections
I am creating the .net.xml file for sumo simulation. After creating, I save it to a Geojson file and use kepler.pl to visualize it, but the road occurs many disconnections. Is there anything wrong with my CFG file parameters. Here are my CFG file parameters:
<input>
    <osm-files value=".osm"/>
    <type-files value=".typ.xml"/>
</input>

<output>
    <output-file value=".net.xml"/>
    <plain-output-prefix value="osm_net_demo"/>
    <output.street-names value="false"/>
    <output.original-names value="true"/>
</output>

<projection>
    <proj.utm value="true"/>
    <proj.plain-geo value="true"/>
</projection>

<processing>
    <geometry.remove value="true"/>
    <geometry.remove.min-length value="250"/>
    <roundabouts.guess value="true"/>
    <ramps.guess value="true"/>
    <edges.join value="true"/>
</processing>

<tls_building>
    <tls.discard-loaded value="false"/>
    <tls.discard-simple value="true"/>
    <tls.guess value="false"/>
    <tls.guess.joining value="true"/>
    <tls.join value="true"/>
    <tls.uncontrolled-within value="true"/>
    <tls.ignore-internal-junction-jam value="true"/>
    <tls.guess-signals value="true"/>
    <tls.yellow.time value="1"/>
    <tls.default-type value="actuated"/>
</tls_building>

<edge_removal>
    <keep-edges.components value="1"/>
    <remove-edges.isolated value="true"/>
</edge_removal>

<junctions>
    <no-internal-links value="true"/>
    <junctions.join-turns value="true"/>
    <junctions.join value="true"/>
</junctions>

<report>
    <verbose value="true"/>
    <xml-validation value="never"/>
    <aggregate-warnings value="5"/>
</report>

The first network is mine, the second network is from another paper:
my network,
paper network
I also use sumo to load the networks, the first one is paper's network, the second one is mine.
paper's network,
my network
How can I fix these disconnections?

Does the network look OK in sumo-gui?

I think so. I just added two images of the sumo-loaded networks. They represent the same road, but my network has more segments compared to the one in the paper. I am wondering which parameter causes my road to be divided into more segments than the one in the paper.

After another look at the network it might contain the internal edges of the junctions, see the updated answer below

If you are using the net2geojson script, try to add the --junctions option. This will add shapes for the connecting nodes and junctions which seem to be missing in your example. If you don't want the polygonal junction shapes but just the connecting lines, try --internal instead.
